# Creating loop to check when paths (ArrayLists) have the same position at same index

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

I have a `Player` class which contains a `path` attribute; the `path` attribute is an `ArrayList<Node>`.

Each `Player`s path can be of different size.

For the current `Player` I want to compare the other `Player` `path`s and see if the same element and index  is the same position; then change the current `path` only.

Example:

```
        for(Player p : listAI()) {
            if(p == bot || p.getPath() == null || path == null) continue;
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(p.getPath().size(), path.size()); i++) {
                if (path.get(i).position.equals(p.getPath().get(i).position)) {
                    path.add(i,MoveType.None);
                }
            }
        }
```

Original Paths:

- currentBot = [5:3,   5:4,  5:5,  6:2]  //bot we are checking
- bot1 = [5:3,   6:4,  7:2,  3:9]
- bot2 = [5:3,   6:2,  7:2,  5:5,  5:8]

The for loop that deals with updating path with a NONE (the one we are trying to figure out); should only change the current bot's path.

To change it:

It should look at other bots paths one at a time. If it finds the same position at the same index then it will update the current bots path only by adding a blank move.

Example loop (bot1 & bot2 paths never change throughout checking):

First iteration: (currentBot checks bot1 to see if it has same position at the same indexes

1. currentBot compares path with bot1
2. currentBot sees index 0 is the same
3. currentBot inserts a blank move at index 0;

currentBot path after first iteration:  [0:0,  5:3,   5:4,  5:5,  6:2]

Second iteration:  (currentBot checks bot2 to see if it has same position at the same indexes

1. currentBot now compares the new path with bot2
2. currentBot sees index 3 is same
3. currentBot inserts a blank move at index 3

currentBot path after 2nd iteration:  [0:0,  5:3,   5:4,  0,0, 5:5,  6:2]

Loop ends:
findPath algorithm returns new path;

---

With this information I only want to modify one of the paths as shown in example above where I basically move the positions over 1 index after adding a blank position.

Can someone help me implement this even if there are different size paths being compared; being as efficient as possible?

Comment: What is the maximum size of playerList and path variables? And also, if path is a List, is size of path and playerList same all the time?

Comment: @BSangappa It can vary. As its an online game. and each paths goal could be different

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashmap like this interger(Key) is index when storing player path or creating player map string is value against it and can be any thing other than String in this case its checking if playerMap have same string at same index like playerPath.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> playerMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        HashMap<Integer, String> playerPath = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < playerMap.size(); i++) {
            if(playerMap.containsKey(i) == playerPath.containsKey(i % playerPath.size())){
                System.out.println("Found where player standing");
        }
}
```

Above code return true if player.path have atleast one value match is playerList

Comment: I want to know if it contains the same on the same elements. Not just if it contains. The players could very well use the same path but I don't want them using it at the same time.

Comment: Donot exactly know what you but contains checks if the given element is present in both the list.
Java Defination: It returns true if the specified element is found in the list else it returns false.

Comment: I need to know if it contains it at the same position in each list

Comment: Then you can use HashMap

Comment: Ok so I have done some example on hashmap to give you an idea there obvious ways to do it only with List but would be too expensive because there would be nested loop and I assue you are already using gameloop which is an overhead also.

Comment: I've updated my post with an example of what i'm getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227359/discussion-between-syed-mohib-uddin-and-dre).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, maintain a **Index List** which stores the **index** positions where **path** List and **playerList** has same values. Once you have index positions of same values, you can do something at those index positions in **path** List.


For example, take a look at below code snippet

```
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    path.add(0);
    path.add(1);
    path.add(5);

    List<Integer> playerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    playerList.add(1);
    playerList.add(5);
    playerList.add(9);
    
    List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    if(playerList.size() < path.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++) {
            if (playerList.get(i) == path.get(i)) {
                indexList.add(i);
            }
        }
    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
            if (playerList.get(i) == path.get(i)) {
                indexList.add(i);
            }
        }
    }       
    System.out.println("Need change/modification in following indexes : " + indexList);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < indexList.size(); i++) {
        //Do something at path.get(i)
    }
```

what we are doing here is, we are checking whether value at index **i** of **path List**  is equal to value at index **i** of **playerList List**. If equal we are can add that index to **indexList**. Once that is done,we can use the index values of **indexList** and **doSomeThing** at those positions of **path List**.


Using if condition we are **checking which List size is less**, if **path List** size is less that **playerList**, then we are looping from **0 to size of path List** OR if **playerList** size is less that **path List** then, **we are looping from 0 to size of playerList**. This condition check helps us to not get IndexOutOfBoundsException.


Hope you get some idea with this approach.

Comment: When I do something similar to your answer; it doesn't give me the expected output